# accessing data member through composition

Tags: c++, object, struct

I have a struct obj in my base class. I don't know how to access the data members of the struct through Derv1 class (Derived from the base class). I tried making both Base and Derv1 a friend of struct - it still tells me ' data member is private' (its private in Base only).

example :

```
struct A{
    public :
        int total;
        //some stuff
};
class MyClass{ // [Base] class
    private:
      A var1;
};

class Derv1{
    private:
        //some stuff
        public void display_var1(Derv1 x){
            return x.var1.total;
        }  // trying to return the value of A.total
};
```

I hope this makes sense so that you can help me out .. 
Thank You kindly,

Comment: Perhaps you can put together a [mcve] so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: Oops that was my screw-up typing it in here - - I actually do have dev1 inherited from Base .. just can't access the struct data member though .. do I have to make the obj protected maybe in the base class ... ???

Comment: Normally if you want to update a question, you can use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55427727/edit) below the question to make changes, but seeing as there are viable answers discussing the problem as posted, it would be bad form to render them invalid. Instead you should take what you have learned here and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must extend your Derv1 class into the Base class:

```
class Derv1: public MyClass{
```

to inherit the members of the base class

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make sure that `Derv` derives from `MyClass`.

```
class Derv1 : public MyClass { ... };
```

and then, you will need to figure out the best way to display the variable.

My suggestion:

1. Create a `virtual` member function in the base class.
2. Override the function in the derived class.
3. Make sure to call the base class implementation in the derived class implementatin.

```
class MyClass { // [Base] class

    public:

        virtual void display() const
        {
           // Display var1 anyway you wish to.
        }

    private:
      A var1;
};

class Derv1 : public MyClass {

    public:

        virtual void display() const
        {
           // Call the base class implementation first
           MyClass::display():

           // Display anything else that corresponds to this class
        }

    private:
        //some stuff
};
```